# MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, events

**Error :**

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 5

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `start_game` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE STARTS '2018-05-05 05:50:07' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DISABLE DO BEGIN
set @game_id = (select id FROM tbl_game where game_status=0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1);

update tbl_game set game_status = 1 where id = @game_id;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `DELIMITER` before and end of the batch.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost EVENT start_game ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE STARTS '2018-05-05 05:50:07' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DISABLE DO BEGIN set @game_id = (select id FROM tbl_game where game_status=0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1);

update tbl_game set game_status = 1 where id = @game_id; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```